# Delivering updated list elements via an otto event to Mortar's screen

Tags: android, dagger, event-bus, otto, mortar

I'm trying to use [Mortar](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/1w63ro/simpler_android_apps_with_flow_and_mortar_eschews/) for a simple application that shows a list of items based on [mortar-sample](https://github.com/square/mortar/tree/master/mortar-sample).

I'm using [Retrofit/Gson](http://www.mdswanson.com/blog/2014/04/07/durable-android-rest-clients.html) to fetch meta-data of these items and Otto to deliver updates to the view once the items are downloaded. I'm also using Dagger for objects creation.

I've an `ItemList` class that implements `ListView` to disply the items in a list, and an `ItemListScreen` that implements `mortar.Blueprint`.

I wonder where is the best place to put the subscribing method that will update the adapter items?
Currently, I'm placing it under `ItemListScreen.Presenter` but the subscribe method is never called!!

```
@Layout(R.layout.item_list_view)
public class ItemListScreen implements Blueprint {
    ...

    @Singleton
    public static class Presenter extends ViewPresenter<ItemListView> {
        ...

        @Subscribe
        public void onEvent(Event event){
            ItemListView view = getView();
            if(view == null) return;
            view.showItems(event.items);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have your presenter hopping on the bus.

```
bus.register(this);
```

Probably want to put that in the onLoad method and then unregister when the view is no longer being displayed.